# What is the total specificity for this CSS Selector? button:not(#mainBtn, .cta)

Tags: css, css-specificity

On MDN Web Docs website, they have mentioned that the total specificity for the selector button:not(#mainBtn, .cta) is as follows:

```
| Selector                    | Identifiers | Classes | Elements | Total specificity

| button:not(#mainBtn, .cta)  | 1           | 0       | 1        | 1-0-1
```

Here is the URL of the MDN Website:
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance.

See the highlighted portion for the error:

[image: See the highlighted portion for the error]

I am expecting this:

```
| Selector                    | Identifiers     | Classes     | Elements      | Total specificity

| button:not(#mainBtn, .cta)  | 1(for #mainBtn) | 1(for .cta) | 1(for button) | 1-1-1
```

I am expecting this:

[image: I am expecting this]

Can someone please let me know if I am right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MDN page you link to covers this, but not, IMO, in a particularly clear fashion. It says:

> The negation (:not()), relational selector (:has()), the matches-any (:is()) pseudo-classes, and CSS nesting themselves don't add to specificity, but their parameters or nested rules do. **The specificity weight that each contributes to the specificity algorithm is the specificity weight of the selector in the parameter or nested rule with the greatest weight.**

[The Selectors specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#specificity-rules) describes it more precisely:

> The specificity of an :is(), :not(), or :has() pseudo-class is replaced by the specificity of the most specific complex selector in its selector list argument.

So, for `:not(#mainBtn, .cta)` we take the greater of the two selectors in the list:

```
#mainBtn = 1, 0, 0
.cta     = 0, 1, 0
```

So the greater of these is 1, 0, 0, and then we add the `button` specificity = 0, 0, 1

And the result is 1, 0, 1.

Comment: Thank you very much @Alohci for clarifying this to me. I understood now why the final result is 1, 0, 1.

Answer (score 0):

The specificity of an `:is()`, `:not()`, or `:has()` pseudo-class is replaced by the specificity of the most specific complex selector in its selector list argument.

https://www.figma.com/file/1ISVRXEq8noFWxAbBhgKzs/(work)?type=design&node-id=609%3A4867&mode=design&t=rNbIRILL60wQbLOY-1

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).